# How can I control a plane in Battlefield Heroes?

Tags: keyboard, battlefield-heroes

Does anybody here have a good grasp on how to successfully control the planes in Battlefield Heroes?

I've fiddled with the sensitivity settings so at least I can bank and whatnot more quickly, but some of the aerial dogfighting and troop-gunning that I've seen seem way beyond my reach.

Any advice on the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a mouse for roll and pitch control, then you should bind 2 keys and/or mouse buttons for pitch control (nose up/nose down) to get the maximum possible pitch change in dogfights. At least it worked like that in BF2.

Answer (score 0):

I had to get a joystick for flying in Battlefield games on PC. I've been using something similar to [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AW9RE).